# Иконки для списка

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Делаю программу для очистки ресурсов пк путем закрытия программ, не внесенных в WhiteList. Для наглядности решил добавить иконки приложений к их названиям, но как это сделать - не имею ни малейшего представления.

Answer (score 2):

Всё просто. Единственная сложность — вам придётся подключить `System.Drawing` для того, чтобы вытащить иконку.

На самом деле, согласно MVVM добыча иконки — задача модели, но я для простоты сделаю это в VM. Получаем следующее:

```
class FileVM
{
    public string Name { get; }
    public ImageSource Icon { get; }
    public FileVM(string path)
    {
        Name = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(path);
        using (var icon = System.Drawing.Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(path))
        {
            Icon = System.Windows.Interop.Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHIcon(
                        icon.Handle, Int32Rect.Empty, BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
        }
    }
}
```

В `DataContext` помещаем, к примеру,

```
var systemFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System);
var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(systemFolder, "*.exe");
var vms = files.Take(20).Select(p => new FileVM(p)).ToList();
```

Простейший XAML:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <ItemContainerTemplate>
            <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
                <Image Source="{Binding Icon}" Height="32" Width="32" DockPanel.Dock="Left"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </DockPanel>
        </ItemContainerTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Получаем:

[image: списочек]

Comment: почему это задача модели? Может представления? Разве не лучше сделать какой-нить энум, а иконки тянуть с конвертера?

Comment: А есть варианты попроще? С учётом того, что список процессов уже набирается используя:
`Process[] processes = Process.GetProcesses();

                foreach (var proc in processes)
                {
                             _combobox.Add(proc.ProcessName);
                            
                }` (это Model)

Comment: @tym32167: Потому что работа с файловой системой? Она имеет право быть медленной.

Comment: @MedBED: Вряд ли. Вам всё равно придётся у процесса разузнать путь к образу, и вытаскивать иконку оттуда. Если у вас нет пути заранее, это только сложнее.

Comment: не понял, причем тут файловая система?

Comment: @tym32167: Ну, добыча иконки из файла = доступ к файловой системе. (`System.Drawing.Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(path)`)

Comment: @VladD Я буквально пару часов назад видел код вроде 
`_Icons.Add(Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(File))`

Comment: @MedBED: Хорошо, а чем это отличается от моего случая? Вы ж в метках написали MVVM не зря? У меня для файла заведена отдельная VM. И ваш код, думаю, для WinForms.

Comment: @VladD Я только сейчас понял в чем прикол...

Comment: я про доступ понял, я не понял, почему это как то волнует модель или вьюмодель?

Comment: @tym32167: Ну, в моём представлении VM синхронно бежит в UI-потоке, так что тяжёлыми операциями заниматься не может. Ну и файловые операции не выглядят для меня по смыслу бизнес-логикой, умение вытащить иконку мне кажется слишком предметным знанием. Вот поэтому я бы и поместил его в модель.

Comment: @tym32167 Ну потому что, он это расположил во ViewModel, её задача в MVVM в принципе это соединение Model и View, при изменение чего-либо во View меняется какое-то свойство Model и наоборот. По сути подобное пишется в Model, View это представление (Окно, контролы и т.п.)

Comment: понял, у нас разное представление о назначении модели, вьюмодели и вью.

Comment: @tym32167: Ага, вечный спор двух школ :)