# Список процессов (иконки)

Tags: c#, mvvm

Пытаюсь сделать список процессов с иконками, но...
В общем и главном код выглядит примерно так:

**View**:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Icons}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
         Height="215" Margin="10,50,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="222"/>
```

**ViewModel**:

```
public ObservableCollection<System.Drawing.Icon> Icons => _model._Icons;
```

**Model**:

```
public Bitmap IconBitmap = null;

Process[] processes = Process.GetProcesses();
foreach (var proc in processes)
{
    _combobox.Add(proc.ProcessName);
    try
    {
        var Icons = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(proc.MainModule.FileName);
        if (Icons != null) IconBitmap = Icons.ToBitmap();
        _Icons.Add(Icons);
    }
    catch
    {
    }
}
```

Ну, а в качестве результата, вместо иконок текст:
(Значок)
(Значок)
(Значок)
(Значок)

Как это исправить? С чем это связано?

Comment: у вас ни одна иконка не отображается?

Comment: ни одной, только этот текст

Comment: А почему не дубликат? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/803120/10105

Answer (score 0):

Потому что WPF не знает, как отображать `System.Drawing.Icon`. `System.Drawing.Icon` — объект фреймворка WinForms, а не WPF.

Как отображать на WPF, есть в ответе на этот вопрос: [Иконки для списка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/803056/10105).